# How to tell Bootstrap Carousel to go to a specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap and Bootstrap Carousel in a project.

I would like to know if there's any way to make the Carousel navigate to a specific slide.
For example, something like:

```
$('myCarousel').to(2);
```

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the documentation:

> .carousel(number) Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based,
>   similar to an array).

So I think it should be:

```
 $('myCarousel').carousel(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the element of your carousel with jQuery and use the `.carousel()` method:

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel(2);
```

This would take you to the third slide.